# Query to find given number belongs to any range in the given table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have a table as

```
Name(String)    fromRange(int)      toRange(int)
abc             15160               15180
bhy             12510               12515
```

Now When I input the Number as 12514

my database query should return the 
value stating that it belongs to the following range 
12510 to 12515 or 
it belongs to the following bhy Name

**Scenario 2**

If I enter the 12530 it should return 0, indicating that its not a part of any range.

**Scenario 3**
If I enter the 15160. it should return the following range as 15160 to 15180

I thought of using the BETWEEN keyword But No luck with that

I am using the SQL server database, can anyone help me with the query

Comment: what do you mean by "it should return 0"? 0 rows or recorset this one column with 0 in it?

Comment: 0 Means No results or any other equivalent statement I can use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
DECLARE @input INT
SELECT @input = 15160

SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE
    input BETWEEN fromRange AND toRange
```

Comment: @input will be number, I cant assign it to the NAME

Comment: Please check updated. As far as I understand you just need that simple query. Only the question I have is about returning 0.

Comment: Works perfectely. I used `SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE
    15160 BETWEEN fromRange AND toRange`

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    name,
    fromRange,
    toRange,
    12514 between fromRange and toRange as is_in_range 
from mean_data
```

`is_in_range` will be `1` if the input is in range, `0` otherwise